# How to dismiss UIActionSheet automatically

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have a requirement where i am showing actionSheet but in case user does not dismiss this actionsheet by selecting one of the option, i want to dismiss this automatically by program on a particular event. Any idea guys, how can i dismiss this actionsheet progratically?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use:

```
- (void)dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex animated:(BOOL)animated
```