# How to programmatically close an ActionSheetIOS in React Native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I can't find a way to programmatically close an [ActionSheetIOS](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/actionsheetios.html). When the device orientation changes, if there is an action sheet open, I need to close it before reopening it (otherwise it is erroneously anchored to the wrong location). I haven't been able to find a way to trigger closing it without requiring user input. Is this possible programmatically?

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.38/docs/actionsheetios.html#actionsheetios) does not mention this being possible in the current version (0.38.0). I also could not find [any related issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=close%20ActionSheetIOS), so the only ideas that comes to mind are either finding a package that implements the functionality [JS.coach](https://js.coach/all/react-native-actionsheet?search=actionsheet), or extending the [implementation of ActionSheetIOS](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/tree/master/Libraries/ActionSheetIOS) to include that functionality. Maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5726408/2628463) might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

React Native version 0.69.0 has added the [`ActionSheetIOS.dismissActionSheet()` method](https://reactnative.dev/docs/actionsheetios#dismissactionsheet), which will dismiss the most upper action sheet.